# Passing table row to function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm super new to angular, and I've been told of it's greatness, but also of it's annoyingly high learning curve. I've been repeatedly smashing my head against the wall now for the better half of 3 hours trying to figure something out.

I couldn't find any documentation on it either. I either don't know what to search, or it isn't possible anymore or something.

```
function modalCtrl($scope, $modal) {

    $scope.openManageMainCd = function() {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/modalManageMainCd.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
        });
    };
    $scope.openLadders = function(e) {

        alert(e);
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/ladderModal.html',
            controller: LadderInstanceCtrl
        });
    };
};    

function LadderInstanceCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ladder = GetLadderData(_facilityData.holdings);
};

function GetLadderData(holdings){
    var holdingData = [];

    angular.forEach(holdings, function(value, key) {
        if (value.type == 'Ladder') {
             angular.forEach(value.cds, function(value, key) {
                var obj = { type: value.type, name: value.name, amount: value.amount, rate: value.rate, maturityDate: value.maturityDate }
                holdingData.push(obj);
             });
        }
    });
    return holdingData;
};
```

This big jumbled mess is what I have created with my time. When a row on my table is clicked, it calls the `openLadders` function. Right now, I've tried sending it everything under the sun, and none of it has helped so far. I want to send it basically the row. There is an ID I need from the row, I just want that ID. I've tried....

`ng-click="openLadders(row)`         ==     function says row is undefined

`ng-click="openLadders($event)`     ==   I have no idea what i am looking at

`ng-click="openLadders($index)`    ==  Doesn't help me

and many more. Angular's website doesn't really go into detail with what I need to know so I was unable to find help there. I have went through two tutorials on Angular on websites which make me believe that it is possible.

Can anyone offer any shred of help here? I'm so lost.

The table is build like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="holding in holdings" ng-if="holding.type == 'Ladder'" class="" ng-controller="modalCtrl" ng-click="openLadders()">
    <td><i class="icon-plus" ></i> {{holding.type}}</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">{{holding.name}}</td>
    <td>{{holding.maturityDate}}</td>
    <td>{{holding.amount | currency:"$"}}</td>
    <td>{{holding.rate | percentage:2}}</td>
</tr>
```

There seems to be an obvious follow up question that I will have, which will be sending that information once I get it from the function `openLadders` to the actual `LadderInstanceCtrl()`. So help on either topic would be severely appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you mind adding to the question details about how the table is build? Might help to see how the table is build to see what `$scope` item it is coming from and what is available.

Comment: Am I right to understand that exists a field `holding.id` that you want passed to `openLadders` ?

Comment: Yes you are. that is 100% correct. @h7r

Comment: ng-click="openLadders(holding.id)"

Comment: Please check my answer. As to the issue of passing to `LadderInstanceCtrl`, I'd suggest reading a bit about Services and Controllers. In Angular's model, `openLadders` would be in the controller, which would have a dependency (injection) to a `LadderInstanceService` (replacing your `LadderInstanceCtrl`). This is more an issue of understanding Angular's adequate application architecture than any specific problem you are facing. Best luck with Angular, which is indeed very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right saying that Angular has a learning curve, but is not so steep once one understands how scoping works.

You are very close to what you wanted, just needed to pass the exact field you needed as a parameter to the function, which might feel a bit different than pure javascript.

What you describe is solved with (note the `ng-click` directive):

```
<tr ng-repeat="holding in holdings" ng-if="holding.type == 'Ladder'" class="" ng-controller="modalCtrl" ng-click="openLadders(holding.id)">
    <td><i class="icon-plus" ></i> {{holding.type}}</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">{{holding.name}}</td>
    <td>{{holding.maturityDate}}</td>
    <td>{{holding.amount | currency:"$"}}</td>
    <td>{{holding.rate | percentage:2}}</td>
</tr>
```

It might be just as convenient, in similar situation, to pass the whole `holding` object with `ng-click="openLadders(holding)"`. Might be instructive to try this too and see the behavior.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh man.... You're amazing.... I swear I tried {{holding.id}} but never just holding.id. I feel so dumb. One step at a time though.

Comment: Basically `{{ }}` executes interpolation for output, and the content is interpreted by Angular. inside the `ng-click` directive (or any other for that matter), there's no need for interpolation, as the variables (from the $scope) are all available directly.  I'm glad that it helped.